# Crystal report taking lot of time to run

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-server

I have a crystal report and it's taking a lot of time to run.It has 164 fields.Most of them are empty formula's and it's susing four tables.The report is using 10 fields from these tables the rest of the fields are empty.

How can I improve the performance of the report?

Thanks.

Comment: If the formulas are empty why are they in the report?

Comment: For CSV output.I need a blank columns in CSV file.They may modify the blank later

Comment: they may load slow for the first time you run them, the next time they will take less time, first time even if the report has minimum fields it takes time, not later.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad.

http://www.supportingadvancement.com/reporting/crystal_reports_tips/dove_subreports.pdf

Above are some good tips.

Crystal reports also has a performance information menu item that tells you how long the database queries as well as other timed items. That will help you figure what is taking so long.

Comment: +1 I haven't seen that document before. I also like [this presentation](http://www.businessobjects.com/pdf/dev_zone/Unchugging_CR_Michitsch.pdf)

Comment: I am not sure if you have the desktop software but it is under Report, Performance Information. I usually look at Performance Timing. I record the values before I make tweaks then I re-run the report. I compare the values to see if my tweaks has improved the execution time.